# Array variable input help [close]

Tags: java, arrays, replace, extend

First of all, I have to create an array of length n, input variables to fill that array, then at array location k, I have to push all arrays location k and up by 1 and put the value of x into array location k. But if k = n, then put x in n+1.

First of all, I am having a problem making the ints for k and x work. For some reason the code sets n to the first input and sets k and x to the same as n immediately when n is set.

Secondly, I am having trouble extending the array to n+1. I know don't just give me the answer but I need some direction on where to go.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw2
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int k = scan.nextInt();
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
     a[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    n++;
    final int LENGTH = a.length - 1;
    for(int j=LENGTH; j>k; j--)
    {
     a[j] = a[j-1];
    }
    a[k] = x;
    for(int h = 0; h < n; h++)
    {
     System.out.println("location " + h + " is " + a[h]);    
    }

   }
}
```

sample input for n k x a[0]... a[n-1] is

```
5  3  7  2  3  5  11  13
```

respectively.

After the code runs with that input, n should = 6 and the array should be

```
a[0] = 2
a[1] = 3
a[2] = 5
a[3] = 7
a[4] = 11
a[5] = 13
```

EDIT: I read the problem completely wrong. A hint at the bottom said "Assume that the array is of at least size n+1"
...

Comment: Is this homework?  (If so, use the appropriate tag, please.)

Comment: The problem description does not capture the full requirements based on looking at your sample output.  Should the array be sorted?  Duplicates removed?

Comment: @GreenMatt I was told that the use of the homework tag, along with all other meta tags, is discouraged.

Comment: @GreenMatt don't use the homework tag.  @John that is correct

Comment: @Woot4Moo @John:  Why not use the homework tag?

Comment: @GreenMatt check out meta.stackoverflow.com and search homework.  Its the first link

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  Following that link led me to [Is homework an exception?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception).  It looks like the debate is still on (and may be until [Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/60495#60495) makes up his mind).

Comment: I'd recommend not using the tag anymore.

Comment: @Jack - I'd recommend ignoring @Woot4Moo, and doing what you think is most likely to get good answers your questions.  I (for one) am much more likely to answer homework questions if they tagged as homework.  And tagging as homework is likely to discourage people from contributing potted solutions ... which I'm sure you don't actually want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything including this is fine:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw2
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int k = scan.nextInt();
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
     a[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

After that is gets a little sketchy. The problem could be interpreted a couple ways...

> then at array location k, input the
>   variable x. But if k = n, then put x
>   in n+1

To me, this means "overwrite" the value in location k unless k == n. As to the couple ways - it depends on how your assignment is worded. If it doesn't matter what size the array is to start with then you could start with your array size being n+1 (or n+someArbitraryValue) instead of n. If you have to keep the size at n or n+1 depending on the k==n check then when k==n you need to setup a new array with size n+1 and copy the values from a into it.

Hope this helps without giving too much away.

Comment: From his code it appears that the array is already filled and that he is inserting into a full array.

Comment: what i mean was to put the value in x at array location k by moving the array up by one so that no values are overwritten just moved up by one and x put in position k

Comment: Well then your choices are to use another array to move things around or to have the array size >= N+1 from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know just what you're asking because your code is inconsistent with what you wrote.  From what I understand the n element array is already filled to capacity.  In this case you can't just append an element at the end, you need to make a new array and copy all of the data from the old array to the new array.

It would work something like this:

```
int[] oldArr = new int[n]; //old array, full
int[] newArr = new int[2*n];//new array
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  new[i] = old[i];
}
```

Then just put k in at new[n+1] like you would normally.  Note that if the array were not empty you would only need to do the above if you were inserting x at n.

Comment: I cannot copy the array. it has to be the same array name.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use ArrayList

Comment: (-1) But that is not what he is asking.